# What happens to people when the universes are rebooted?

Tags: dc

I hear that the DC universes are "rebooted" every now and then. What happens to the people/aliens/creatures that live in it when the whole universes are "rebooted"? Do they all die?  When infinite Earths collapse into only 52, where do all the rest of the people go?

Comment: They all cease to exist unless they have the power to resist

Comment: Do they have the power to resist? "cease to exist" means "die"?@Valorum

Comment: Yes, they all die.

Comment: That's horrible...didn't Superman or Batman figure out some idea to save everyone?

Comment: Superman isn't god. Even gods were annihilated when the multiverses collapsed.

Comment: What happens to people when the universes are rebooted? They head to their nearest comic store in [unimaginable numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crisis_on_Infinite_Earths#Reception)!

Comment: For a non-DC take, you might be interested in _Astro City_ #1/2, "The Nearness of You"

Comment: There's some reference to the nature of the universes being rebooted causing some kind of negative effect on the fabric of reality when the Justice League take on the Anti Monitor.

Answer (score 1):

They are completely undone, which seems to be a slightly different action. They are not and never were, so they didn´t suffer if that´s a consolation.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence to back up this bold statement?

Comment: When the original Crisis on Infinite Earths happened, Superman had his backstory rewritten, Wonder Woman was unmade to have never existed, The Flash was killed and replaced, and Batman mostly was business as usual.

Comment: This isn't entirely accurate. The rewriting of universes has been mentioned as an event that is quantifiable by the members of the Justice League at some point, I believe during or shortly following their fight with the AntiMonitor.